# Breadcrumbs Navigate Up in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, web-part, document-library

I have Project Document Library, it contains few `sub-folders` are created.

And I insert this document library in a page as `List View web part`.

Now when we enter into sub-folders can't get back or navigate back to root folders in list view web part.

How to create `Back button` in document library web part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <style>
> #NavigationBar{
> padding: 6px;
> /* padding-bottom: 6px; */
> padding-left: 10px;
> padding-right: 10px;
> display: inline;
> border-radius: 7px;
> font-family: fantasy;
> /* border: 0; */
> margin: px;
> background: #1b9e92;
> font-size: 15px;
> /* line-height: 15px; */
> color: #ff0258;
> width: auto;
> height: auto;
> box-sizing: content-box;
> }
> </style>
> ```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Variable to store the text used by SharePoint to generate the breadcrumb separator arrows
 var SeparatorArrow = '<span id="onetidPageTitleSeparator"><span><span style="height:11px;width:11px;position:relative;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;"><img src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" alt=":" style="border-width:0px;position:absolute;left:-0px !important;top:-585px !important;" /></span></span> </span>';
 var baseURL = (document.location).toString();
 baseURL = baseURL.substring(0,baseURL.indexOf(".aspx")+5);
 var url = baseURL;                             
 url = baseURL + '?RootFolder=';
 var rootFolder = unescape(GetUrlParameter('RootFolder'));      
 var path = GetFolderPath(rootFolder);   
 rootFolder = rootFolder.substring(0,rootFolder.indexOf(path));  
 if(path.length > 0)
 {
     var folders = path.split('/');
     for(var i=0; i < folders.length; i++)
     {
          if(i==0)                             
                url += encodeURIComponent(rootFolder.substring(0,rootFolder.length-1));
          url += encodeURIComponent('/' + folders[i]);
          //insert row
          var urlok=url.replace('%2F%2F','%2F');
          if(i<folders.length-1)
          {
               //Add the folder link and separator arrows if more than one folder level deep
               // and change URL to URLOK down
               document.write('<a id="NavigationBar" href="' + urlok + '&FolderCTID=' + GetUrlParameter("FolderCTID") + '&View=' + GetUrlParameter("View") + '">' + folders[i] + '</a>');
               document.write(SeparatorArrow);
          }
          else
          {
               if(folders.length>1)
               document.write(folders[i]);
          }             
     }
 }  
 // Gets the value of the requested URL Parameter
 function GetUrlParameter( name )
 {
 name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
 var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
 var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
 var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
 if( results == null ) return "";
 else return results[1];
 }
 // Gets the name of the library
 function GetFolderPath(rootFolder)
 {
 var domain = window.location.hostname;
 var web = baseURL.substring(baseURL.indexOf(domain)+domain.length);
 var path = rootFolder.substring(GetFirstBreakIndex(web, rootFolder));
 return path;
 }
 // Gets the first different character occurrence index
 function GetFirstBreakIndex(a, b)
 {
 var slashIndex = -1;
 var equalsReturnCode = -1;
 if (a && b)
 {
      var longest = b.length > a.length ? b : a;
      var shortest = a.length > b.length ? b : a;
      for(var i=0; i < shortest.length; i++)
      {
           // Get location of each / as a breakpoint if
           // the first break index is part way into the string
           if(shortest.charAt(i) == '/')
                slashIndex = i;
           if(shortest.charAt(i) != longest.charAt(i))
           {
                if(i-slashIndex == 1)
                     return i;
                else
                     return slashIndex + 1;
           }
      }
 }
 else
 {
      return equalsReturnCode;
 }
 }
 </script>
```

Add this code in `Script Editor or Content Editor` on top of your document library web part.

It will display as below image

[image]